# javascript catch do not work

Tags: javascript, jquery

I have the next example using jQuery:

```
try{

   $.post(url,data, function(response){
       throw 'Exception';
   });
}catch(e){
      alert('Error'); 
}
```

But the line: `alert('Error')` is never executed. What is happening here?

Comment: `$.post` is asynchronous. It won’t synchronously throw an error.

Comment: is the code in the `try` being executed?

Comment: By the time the asynchronous callback function is executed, the flow has long since left the `try` block.  `$.post()` *itself* doesn't throw an exception.

Answer (score 2):

You're exception is thrown asynchronously, so the exception will not be caught.

The correct way to deal with this is

```
$.post(url,data, function(response){
   throw 'Exception';
}).catch(function(ex){
    alert('Error'); 
});
```

Comment: note that this require jquery 3.0 or later

Comment: @CStff other way round, as of 3.0 it is `.fail(func)`. (The jqXHR.success(), jqXHR.error(), and jqXHR.complete() callback methods are removed as of jQuery 3.0. You can use jqXHR.done(), jqXHR.fail(), and jqXHR.always() instead. - from https://api.jquery.com/jquery.post/)

Comment: @CStff thanks for sharing. Did it work?

Comment: I tried my code using "catch" and "fail' but seems that they don't handle exceptions, only errors related to the connection. Even "always" is ignored.